# How to deal with public void paint() method in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

My problem is that when i use

```
 public void paint(Graphics g)
 {}
```

Method to draw a String as

```
 g.drawString("hello java",0,0);
```

My full code is

```
import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
class test
extends JFrame
{
public void testing()
{
setSize(500,500);
show();
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{ super.paint(g);
g.drawString("HELLO JAVA");
}
public static void main(String arg[])
{
test t=new test();
t.testing();
} }
```

In JFrame i am getting a black screen without hello java being drawn
Please help me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: That's not enough information to give a qualified answer. Please give us a minimal working example of your problem. -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example

Comment: maybe calling `super.paint(g)` first would help

Comment: See examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11567852/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3845270/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the inherited frame correctly, the paint method in the inherited class should contain the call of super.paint():

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawString("hello java", 50, 50);
    }

}
```

EDIT (painting in the panel):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CustomPaint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("CustomPaint");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new MyPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(320, 240);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        String msg = "HELLO JAVA";
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
        int w = (getWidth() - g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(msg)) / 2;
        g2.drawString(msg, w, getHeight() / 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't override paint() on a JFrame!!! Custom painting is done by overriding paintComponent() on a JPanel and then you add the panel to the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: You are right camickr. Priyank, see the edited post.